# C# running external batch and java file

Tags: c#, .net, pos-tagger

I am using the Stanford POS-tagger application to tag some articles in about 300 files. To do this, I wrote a C# code that will go through the files and use the tagger.

My code looks like this:

```
Process thisProcess=new Process();
thisProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow=true;
thisProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
thisProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory=@"C:\postagger";
thisProcess.StartInfo.FileName=@"C:\postagger\stanford-postagger.bat";
thisProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=false;
thisProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput=true;

if(Directory.Exists(@"C:\brown2")) {
    DirectoryInfo brown=new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\brown2");
    DirectoryInfo brownParsed;

    if(!Directory.Exists(@"C:\brown-parsed"))
        brownParsed=Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\brown-parsed");
    else
        brownParsed=new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\brown-parsed");

    FileInfo[] files=brown.GetFiles();

    foreach(FileInfo f in files) {

        Console.WriteLine("Parsing file "+f.Name+" ...");
        thisProcess.StartInfo.Arguments=@"C:\postagger\models\wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger "+f.FullName;
        //Console.WriteLine(thisProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);
        thisProcess.Start();
        thisProcess.WaitForExit();
        //Console.Read();
        StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(brownParsed.FullName, f.Name), false);
        string output=thisProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //sw.Write(thisProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        sw.Write(output);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        //Console.WriteLine("File {0} done!",f.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Dir not found!");

Console.Read();
```

And the stanford-postagger.bat looks like this:

> usage: stanford-postagger model textFile
> e.g., stanford-postagger models\left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger sample-input.txt
>
> java -mx300m -cp "stanford-postagger.jar;" edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model %1 -textFile %2

The problem is:

The code runs it, but it will **NOT** run the java command. I tried it on my laptop, and it works like a charm, it tags. But it won't tag large files due to not enough memory. But on my PC, which is more powerfull, it will not run the java.

If I open the CMD and enter that java command with the right parameters for a file, it works. Any ideea of what may cause it not to work? All the paths are good, I triple checked them.

Here is an example of output I get from the non-working program(on my PC):

> C:\postagger>java -mx300m -cp "stanford-postagger.jar;" edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model C:\postagger\models\wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger -textFile C:\brown2\aaa.txt

Comment: Is the laptop and the desktop using the same bit OS ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain about running a batch file using this, but perhaps using Process to execute it?

```
var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "path-to-file.bat"
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: It's not the bat file execution, that works, the batch file execute itself, but the java thing won't go on

Comment: what happens when you type "java -version" into your normal command line (cmd.exe)?

Comment: it works. funny thing, if i run it from CMD it works. If i type "java -version" in my cmd, it shows my the java version, 1.7.0_17. But, i changed my batch file instead of "java arguments here" to ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" arguments here" and it worked. Weird stuff :)

Comment: "java" is an environment variable that would just execute that exact file anyhow. I don't believe that environment variables are user-specific, but perhaps that could be an issue? At least it's solved however.